# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a learning curve for my MLP, why am I getting the following error? Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

```
X_normalized, y_for_normalized = scaled_df[[ "Part's Z-Height (mm)","Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)","Material's Density (g/cm^3)","Layer Height (mm)","Infill Density (%)","Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)","Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)"]], scaled_df [["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)","Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)","Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)","Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)","Freshwater Consumption (m^3)","Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)","Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)","Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)","Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)","Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)","Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)","Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)","Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)"]]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_normalized, y_for_normalized, test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

mlp_new = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(300,300),
                       max_iter = 100000,activation = 'relu',
                       solver = 'adam', learning_rate='constant', 
                       alpha=0.1,random_state=42,early_stopping=False) #,validation_fraction=0.2
mlp_new.fit(X_train, y_train)
mlp_new_y_predict = mlp_new.predict((X_test))
#mlp_new_y_predict
from yellowbrick.model_selection import (
    learning_curve,
    validation_curve,
    cv_scores)
#ax = plt.gca()
#ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
#ax.set_ylabel("Calorie Burnage")
learning_curve(
    estimator=mlp_new,
    X=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    cv=4,
    train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1,1.0,5),
    n_jobs=1,
    random_state=0,
    scoring='r2',   )
```

#Full Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
    968 
    969             if method is not None:
--> 970                 return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    971             return None
    972         else:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs)
    610     def _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs):
    611         """Mime bundle used by jupyter kernels to display estimator"""
--> 612         output = {"text/plain": repr(self)}
    613         if get_config()["display"] == "diagram":
    614             output["text/html"] = estimator_html_repr(self)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    236         )
    237 
--> 238         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    239 
    240         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    151     def pformat(self, object):
    152         sio = _StringIO()
--> 153         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    154         return sio.getvalue()
    155 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    168             self._readable = False
    169             return
--> 170         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    171         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    172         if len(rep) > max_width:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    429 
    430     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
--> 431         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
    432                                                 self._depth, level)
    433         if not readable:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
    187 
    188     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
--> 189         return _safe_repr(
    190             object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only=self._changed_only
    191         )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    438         recursive = False
    439         if changed_only:
--> 440             params = _changed_params(object)
    441         else:
    442             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
    111         return False
    112 
--> 113     return {k: v for k, v in params.items() if has_changed(k, v)}
    114 
    115 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    111         return False
    112 
--> 113     return {k: v for k, v in params.items() if has_changed(k, v)}
    114 
    115 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in has_changed(k, v)
     99         if k not in init_params:  # happens if k is part of a **kwargs
    100             return True
--> 101         if init_params[k] == inspect._empty:  # k has no default value
    102             return True
    103         # try to avoid calling repr on nested estimators

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    392                         if cls is not object \
    393                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 394                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    395 
    396             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    698     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    699     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 700     output = repr(obj)
    701     lines = output.splitlines()
    702     with p.group():

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    236         )
    237 
--> 238         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    239 
    240         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    151     def pformat(self, object):
    152         sio = _StringIO()
--> 153         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    154         return sio.getvalue()
    155 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    168             self._readable = False
    169             return
--> 170         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    171         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    172         if len(rep) > max_width:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    429 
    430     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
--> 431         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
    432                                                 self._depth, level)
    433         if not readable:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
    187 
    188     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
--> 189         return _safe_repr(
    190             object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only=self._changed_only
    191         )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    438         recursive = False
    439         if changed_only:
--> 440             params = _changed_params(object)
    441         else:
    442             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
    111         return False
    112 
--> 113     return {k: v for k, v in params.items() if has_changed(k, v)}
    114 
    115 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    111         return False
    112 
--> 113     return {k: v for k, v in params.items() if has_changed(k, v)}
    114 
    115 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in has_changed(k, v)
     99         if k not in init_params:  # happens if k is part of a **kwargs
    100             return True
--> 101         if init_params[k] == inspect._empty:  # k has no default value
    102             return True
    103         # try to avoid calling repr on nested estimators

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _repr_html_inner(self)
    606         on `get_config()["display"]`.
    607         """
--> 608         return estimator_html_repr(self)
    609 
    610     def _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_estimator_html_repr.py in estimator_html_repr(estimator)
    391         style_template = Template(_STYLE)
    392         style_with_id = style_template.substitute(id=container_id)
--> 393         estimator_str = str(estimator)
    394 
    395         # The fallback message is shown by default and loading the CSS sets

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    236         )
    237 
--> 238         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    239 
    240         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    151     def pformat(self, object):
    152         sio = _StringIO()
--> 153         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    154         return sio.getvalue()
    155 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    168             self._readable = False
    169             return
--> 170         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    171         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    172         if len(rep) > max_width:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    429 
    430     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
--> 431         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
    432                                                 self._depth, level)
    433         if not readable:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
    187 
    188     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
--> 189         return _safe_repr(
    190             object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only=self._changed_only
    191         )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    438         recursive = False
    439         if changed_only:
--> 440             params = _changed_params(object)
    441         else:
    442             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
    111         return False
    112 
--> 113     return {k: v for k, v in params.items() if has_changed(k, v)}
    114 
    115 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    111         return False
    112 
--> 113     return {k: v for k, v in params.items() if has_changed(k, v)}
    114 
    115 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in has_changed(k, v)
     99         if k not in init_params:  # happens if k is part of a **kwargs
    100             return True
--> 101         if init_params[k] == inspect._empty:  # k has no default value
    102             return True
    103         # try to avoid calling repr on nested estimators

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error?

Comment: @SuperStormer. Done. Having said that, the code gives the error but keeps executing further line of codes.

Comment: There are hundreds of previous questions about that error message. Have you looked at them first?